# Silverlight is giving me an error stating that a .dll file is not enabled?

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to write a simple Silverlight application that has a few button on it but I keep receiving this error. I have gone file explorer to see about changing the permissions of the file so that MS Studio can find it but so far have found nothing to change.

**Question: Is there something that has to be change in Visual Studio for Silverlight to work?**

Silverlight 4 is what my target will be for the WEBApplication.

I am not really certain what needs to be added to this question to make it so that everyone will know what I am asking. I think that it is just a file from MS that has to be enabled and that was the SilverlightApplication3.dll but I am having no real luck enabling it.

Error:

```
Error   1   Could not load the assembly file:///C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\C++\SilverlightApplication3\SilverlightApplication3\obj\Debug\SilverlightApplication3.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more information.
```

XML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,64,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,93,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,122,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Image Height="124" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,156,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="332" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,24,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251">
            <TextBox Height="102" Name="textBox1" Width="221" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SilverlightApplication3
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SilverlightApplication3
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        public App()
        {
            this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
            this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
            this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
        }

        private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the app is running outside of the debugger then report the exception using
            // the browser's exception mechanism. On IE this will display it a yellow alert 
            // icon in the status bar and Firefox will display a script error.
            if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {

                // NOTE: This will allow the application to continue running after an exception has been thrown
                // but not handled. 
                // For production applications this error handling should be replaced with something that will 
                // report the error to the website and stop the application.
                e.Handled = true;
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { ReportErrorToDOM(e); });
            }
        }

        private void ReportErrorToDOM(ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string errorMsg = e.ExceptionObject.Message + e.ExceptionObject.StackTrace;
                errorMsg = errorMsg.Replace('"', '\'').Replace("\r\n", @"\n");

                System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + "\");");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Clean the solution `TopMenu>Build>Clean Solution` (which is basically the equivalent of deleting your /bin and /obj folders if you want to do it manually) and rebuild it. You don't need to care about the crap in your bin and obj folders as it gets replaced correctly on your next build. Cheers.....oh, and welcome to SO :)

Comment: I tried that and still received the same error.

Comment: Then just manually delete `C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\C++\SilverlightApplication3\SilverlightApplication3\obj\` the obj folder, and rebuild it. No worries.